# How to scale an aws ecs service based on multiple alarms

Tags: amazon-web-services, devops, autoscaling, aws-ecs

We have a service running in aws ecs that we want to scale in and out based on 2 metrics.

**Scale out when:** cpu > 80% *or* connection_count > 9500
**Scale in when:** cpu < 50% *and* connection_count < 5000

We have access to both the cpu and connection count metrics and alarms in cloud watch. However, we can't figure out how to setup a dynamic scaling policy like this based on both of them.

Using the standard aws console interface for creating the auto scaling rules I don't see any options for multiple. Any links to a tutorial or aws docs on this would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the responses posted in the support aws forums, nothing can be done for AND/OR/IF conditions. (https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=94984)

It does mention however that they already put a feature request to the cloudwatch team.

The following is mentioned as a workaround:
"In the meantime, a possible workaround can be to create a custom metric using a custom script which would run after every five minutes and get the data points from the CloudWatch metrics, then perform the AND or OR operation and then push the output to a custom metric. You can then create a CloudWatch alarm which would monitor this custom metric and then trigger actions accordingly."